# How to get anti-aliasing in a render

Tags: rendering, antialiasing

I'm learning Blender, and I haven't changed any settings from the default. The viewport has perfect anti-aliasing, but the render is jagged. This happens in Eevee and Cycles. The first pic is the viewport, and the second is a render.

[image: Viewport anti-aliased correctly]

[image]

Comment: #1, the cube is red, so you had to have changed something. But anyway, without changing the default file At All, does it still render this way?

Comment: Yes, the default scene does this too. I'm using 2.92, and that's the one that has this problem, but in 2.8 it's fine.

Comment: That’s really weird. Check render samples, I guess